# How to manage the state with ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter

So I'm trying to make an app that is requesting images from an API. Before the request is completed, the app displays the error (that red background with yellow letters), but once it has loaded, the widgets are properly displayed.

[image: My app after loaded]

Each card here is being rendered by a ListView.builder widget, where the data is being passed for each card. The image of the card is accessed by making a request for an images API, where I randomly select an image through passing a query word (in this case, the name of the country).

The way I'm doing this (not sure if it's the correct way by the way) is by having a `getImage` method (who has `setState` call after the request is done) ,that is called in the `initState()` of the widget.

This is part of the code of my card widget:

```
  String _img;
  bool isLoading = true;

  Future<String> getImage() async {
    String imgURL = await PexelAPI.getImage(widget._country);
    setState(() {
      _img = imgURL;
      isLoading = false;
    });

    return "Data loaded";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getImage();
  }
```

What I want to do, is access that `isLoading`, so I can have a `CircularProgressIndicator` widget before all of the cards are loaded.

How do I do that?

Since the code is preety big, I'm not sure what I should include here. So you if need to see any of the code to answer, I'll add it to the post.

Comment: I think it would help to add the build method that creates the Image. However, as I understand, I think I would first render a custom image from the assets, then I would start the sequence of obtaining the URL from the API (ie: your PexelAPI), which consequently starts requesting the actual image.

Comment: That could work, but since this is an app that i'm using to learn flutter, I want to understand how I could have a loading widget instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a FutureBuilder in the view? Something like this:

```
Future<String> isDataLoaded;
```

in the initState():

```
isDataLoaded = getImages();
```

In the view:

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: isDataLoaded,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
       return snapshot.hasData 
       ? WIDGET 
       : CircularProgressIndicator();              
      }
```

Comment: This will cause an API request every time a list item is built

Comment: That's gonna happen either way in this case. Since I dont have an API that gives me all the data at once ( because I'm using in code dummy data for everything but the images), each card makes a request to the API to get an image that represents it's country.

Comment: So I tried implementing this, and now I'm getting this error:

https://i.imgur.com/GcEzyro.png

I've checked if the URL being passed is right, and it is.

This is the code: https://i.imgur.com/ScAvVQ6.png

Comment: @JonahWilliams is right, answer edited. Try this one.